# Lipschitz function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is it possible to define explicitly a Lipschitz function $f:[a,b]\times[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in term of $f(a,\cdot)$, $f(b,\cdot)$, $f(\cdot,c)$, $f(\cdot,d)$ if I know these functions and they are Lipschitz? 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But it looks an awful lot like homework...

Comment: I am not so sure this is homework. Could the original poster please expand on how they came to consider this question, which partial results they have already found, and so forth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a=c=0$ and $b=d=1$, define $f$ by 
affine interpolation between $f(x+y,0)$ and $f(0,x+y)$ if $x+y\leq 1$ respectively
$f(x+y-1,1)$ and $f(1,x+y-1)$ if $x+y\geq 1$.

The general case can be reduced to the previous one by an affine transformation.

Comment: Nice answer, why somebody downvoted it? 

Comment: I guess I could have left it as a comment: It was really more of an exercice.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that the data define a Lipschitz function on the boundary of the square, and recall that any real-valued Lipschitz function defined on a subset of a metric space always admits a Lipschitz extension to the whole metric space, with the same Lipschitz constant. There exists the minimal and the maximal such extension ([here's the maximal one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties)).